# Deserialize bad json

Tags: c#, json, servicestack, deserialization

I have a json response from a third-party application, that looks like this:

```
{
    1: {
        number: 1,
        headline: Nyttigt,
        value: 9,
        type: value
    },
    2: {
        number: 4,
        headline: ,
        value: 0,
        type: order
    },
    3: {
        number: 5,
        headline: Generellt-Sortiment/utbud,
        value: 9,
        type: value
    },
    4: {
        number: 5,
        headline: Generellt-Leveranser,
        value: 9,
        type: value
    },
    5: {
        number: 5,
        headline: ,
        value: 0,
        type: order
    }
}
```

I am trying to deserialize it using *ServiceStack's* `JsonObject.Parse(jsonResult);`

The problem is that the json gets cut:

[image]

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: this doesn't look like JSON (but instead an object literal).  If you stringify it first does it parse correctly?

Comment: Looks more like a python dictionary - even for that it's missing quoting.

Comment: The third party application is providing you invalid JSON.  So, it will not parse correctly with a JSON deserializer.

Comment: do the thirdparty provide any class/hint on how to deserialize their output?

Comment: @birdypme nope, but i will ask them now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you have isn't JSON but without whitespace it is valid [JSV format](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/wiki/JSV-Format). ServiceStack.Text supports serialising and deserialising JSV.

So given the data:

> {1:{number:1,headline:Nyttigt,value:9,type:value},2:{number:4,headline:,value:0,type:order},3:{number:5,headline:Generellt-Sortiment/utbud,value:9,type:value},4:{number:5,headline:Generellt-Leveranser,value:9,type:value},5:{number:5,headline:,value:0,type:order}}

and the DTOs:

```cs
public class Item
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Headline { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public ItemType Type { get; set; }
}

public enum ItemType
{
    value,
    order
}
```

You can deserialise it:

```cs
var data = "{1:{number:1 ....";
var items = data.FromJsv<Dictionary<int,Item>> ();
```

So you could use a request filter to deserialise the request from JSV into your DTO.

Answer (score 1):

The Json strings should be wrapped in double quotes, for example:

```
{
"1": {
    "number": 1,
    "headline": "Nyttigt",
    "value": 9,
    "type": "value"
},
"2": {
    "number": 4,
    "headline": "",
    "value":0,
    "type": "order"
}}
```

How did you build the response?

Comment: the response is from a third-party application.